# Openfire Http binding doesnot start

Tags: xmpp, openfire

Openfire Http binding doesnot start

When I go on my_ip_address:7070, I have this message :

Error 404 - Not Found.
No context on this server matched or handled this request.
Contexts known to this server are:

```
/http-bind ---> o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/http-bind,null}
/ ---> o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
/http-bind ---> o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/http-bind,null}
/ ---> o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
/http-bind ---> o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/http-bind,null}
/ ---> o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
/http-bind ---> o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/http-bind,null}
/ ---> o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
/http-bind ---> o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/http-bind,null}
/ ---> o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you have to go to  `http://my_ip_address:7070/http-bind/` not to  `my_ip_address:7070`.

Also keep in mind that many servers show nothing or error pages when you access these Urls with a webbrowser. While they work fine when you access them over an XMPP client over BOSH on the same Url.

Comment: Ok Thanks, Url is same as [http://my_ip_address:7070/http-bind/](http://my_ip_address:7070/http-bind/) but the above error shown.